# Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my C++ code

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int array1 [70];
string array2 [1000];

void numgenerate (void)
{
    int marks,count; 

    for (count=0 ; count<71 ; count++)
    {
        marks = rand() % 101;
        array1 [count] = marks;

        if(marks>=82)
            array2 [count]="A+";
        else if(marks>=74 && marks<81)
            array2 [count]="A";
        else if(marks>=66 && marks<73)
            array2 [count]="B";
        else if(marks>55 && marks<65)
            array2 [count]="B-";
        else if(marks>=68 && marks<55)
            array2 [count]="C";
        else if(marks>=61 && marks<68)
            array2 [count]="C-";
        else if(marks>=54 && marks<61)
            array2 [count]="D";
        else 
            array2 [count]="F";

    }
}

void createfile (void)
{
    numgenerate();

    ofstream file( "G:\\student grade and number file.txt", ios::out );

    if(!file)
    {
        cerr << "File could not be opened" << endl;
        exit( 1 );
    }

    for (int count=0 ; count<=70 ; count++)
    {
        file<<setw(4)<<array1 [count]<<"      "<<array2 [count]<<endl;
    }
}

void main ()
{
    createfile();
    system ("pause");

    return ;
}
```

I keep getting the following error

```
Unhandled exception at 0x61ee797f (msvcp90d.dll) in NEW PROJECT.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000004b.
```

Can anyone tell me why i keep getting this error and how to correct my code if you can please you will be of great help.

Comment: Its messy and very hard to read thats one problem.

Comment: Access violation error means most probably that you are reading out of array size -> check array references and indexes to arrays that they arent too high (or too low).

Comment: When you used the debugger, which line was at fault?

Comment: Tell your instructor to inform the class on using a debugger.

Comment: You also have an issue with your `marks` ranges not covering 0 to 100 completely. You could simplify that code a lot by using only `>=` for the tests: `if (marks >= 82) ...; else if (marks >= 74) ...; else if ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exit condition of your `for` loop

```
for (count=0 ; count<71 ; count++)
```

should be

```
for (count=0 ; count<70 ; count++)
```

In this way, when `count == 70`, the loop is not executed. If you execute your loop with `count == 70`, you are out of bounds of your array, whose length is 70 (elements from 0 to 69).

As LumpN pointed out, also the second loop is wrong:

```
for (int count=0 ; count<=70 ; count++)
```

Even in this case you are trying to write out of array bounds as the loop is executed also when `count == 70`

Comment: Please tell him why. Also note that there is a second loop `count <= 70` that is also wrong.

Comment: THANKS A LOAD man i dont know how i missed that, btw how did you deduce that, unfortunately i never learnt how to debug my codes properly if you could also guide me and tell me someplace from where i can learn to debug my codes. :D

Comment: @TahaJamshed if you want to learn to debug your code, then write only one-two lines at a time, compile, test, repeat.  That way, as soon as you make a mistake, you will know (roughly, hopefully) which line introduced it.  A lot of beginners write a giant wall of text in one fell swoop, and then have no clue where to begin when it doesn't compile or crashes.

Comment: @TahaJamshed The exception you encountered is typical of out of bound writings, with time you'll learn that almost all for loops should have index < ArraySize as exit condition. How to debug your code depends of the OS and IDE you are using.

Comment: i am using windows 8 and visual studio 2010

Comment: @TahaJamshed Then you could start following this guide: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn

Comment: @Teejay: If this answer has solved your problem you should consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

Valid indecies for the first array are 0 - 69 because the array has 70 elements. So the following loops are invalid

```
for (count=0 ; count<71 ; count++)

for (int count=0 ; count<=70 ; count++)
```

Must be

```
for ( int count = 0 ; count < 70 ; count++ )
```

Also it is a good idea to define corresponding constant naming this magic number. For example

```
const int N = 70;
```

and then in loops to use this constant

```
for ( int count = 0 ; count < N ; count++ )
```

Also function main shall have return type int

```
int main()
```

Also I see a contradiction in the conditions of the following if-else statements

```
    if(marks>=82)
        array2 [count]="A+";

    else if(marks>=74 && marks<81)
        array2 [count]="A";

    else if(marks>=66 && marks<73)
        array2 [count]="B";

    else if(marks>55 && marks<65)
        array2 [count]="B-";

    else if(marks>=68 && marks<55)
        array2 [count]="C";

    else if(marks>=61 && marks<68)
        array2 [count]="C-";

    else if(marks>=54 && marks<61)
        array2 [count]="D";

    else 
        array2 [count]="F";
```

Compare for example marks B- and C.